# Why can't I push to an array in Mongoose/Express with this code?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here's my schema/model:

```
var todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  item: [String]
});
```

And here is the put method

```
app.put('/todo/:id', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
        { "$push": { "item": req.body } },
        { "new": true, "upsert": true },
        function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(data);
        }
    );
});
```

What ought to happen is it grabs the id (:id), and finds the ID, and pushes req.body (Which is a string, an input from the web page) and pushes it on to the item array.

I am receiving the following error when this put is called:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id" at path "_id" for model "Todo"
```

Which is strange, since I don't explicitly cast the id as an ObjectId when I use findById().

Answer (score 0):

code is correct.i think may be your query id is not a valid objectId so that it cast the error..it must be string of 12 bytes..check it? if its correct means also check  mongoose version, may be this also problem..so install the mongoose version 4

Comment: I've gotten it to stop failing whenever I press the button - but the database isn't getting strings pushed to it (they start empty, and are staying empty). I'm not receiving any errors in console

Comment: inside the put method print the query values..console.log("req.query",req.query) and check that id value is string of 12 bytes like that "59b67565c8745e27f9f3cf46"

Comment: I am finding that putting console.log isn't actually printing any data out when the put method ought to be being called.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose's _id default type is ObjectId. This is why it happening you are passing _id to string value.

Mongoose's findByIdAndUpdate method casts the id parameter to the type of the model's _id field so that it can properly query for the matching doc. This is an ObjectId but "req.params.id" is not a valid ObjectId so the cast fails.

This doesn't happen with 59b67565c8745e27f9f3cf46 because that string is a valid ObjectId.

One way to resolve this is to add a check prior to your findByIdAndUpdate call to see if id is a valid ObjectId or not like so:

```
if (req.params.id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
  // Yes, it's a valid ObjectId, proceed with `findById` call.
}
```

Another way to do it that you can parse the string to ObjectId like:

```
ObjectId.fromString( req.params.id )
```